# Uploading images so that they are searchable

Tags: media, search

How would I go about uploading images so that they are searchable, and so that the search results are actually displaying the image thumbnails?

How difficult would it be to integrate this search into the site search?

Comment: It took Google years to implement image search. So, if you want to recreate their work, you need a lot of money and enthusiasm. If you want some texts associated with images to be searchable, and display results with thumbnails, consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here. Searchable by what parameter? Alt text? Fields on some sort of entity that the image is attached to? Or (and what I expect) are you expecting to get a free library that will 'read' images for you, identify their content, and derive contextual keywords automatically? Either way we need a lot more information, and you'll need to do your own research into the subject before asking for help here. This could be quite a specialised subject so you'll probably be looking to hire an external consultant to advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Google's search server to put next to yours for GSA]

Surest way to make the **images themselves** searchable, is to order [Google Search Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/). It will index them for you, not only data from texts around them, but also the very images themselves. You can easily connect it to Drupal using [Google Search Appliance module](https://drupal.org/project/google_appliance). It's issue queue claims it supports thumbnails, and if it does not support images yet, it should be relatively easy to add it, especially with Google support you need to buy to get GSA.

Comment: Thank you @Molot
Does GSI search by file name, alt text, or is it simple to set it up so that it searches any filed? ALso, will I still need a separate content type and for each image to have its own node?

Comment: GSI search by file name, alt text, the very content of image (it can kinda "see" them), and it does not care about content types in particular. It can even be set up to search your site without site cooperation at indexing.

Comment: I LOL'd hard! Good one!

Comment: @timofey excuse me, but what's so funny about it? It is pretty solid solution. Black box one, but I've seen it working at it did what it advertised. For some it may be worth it's price.

Comment: My bad! Knowing the price for one of these, I totally thought you were being sarcastic! But yeah, it's doable:)

Answer (score 1):

To include image data in the core search index, you perhaps could implement [hook_search_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_info/7) and [hook_search_index](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_update_index/7) to add the custom image field text attributes (alt, title text etc..) to the search index.

You can then theme the output of the search results by overriding [search-result.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7) or using [hook_preprocess_search_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) to add the image thumbnail.

Further core [Search API docs here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/7)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to search by name then you could use the [Apache Solr Attachments module](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments)  which would search the file by its name and if you wish to search by image you should use integrate with Google Search and for more details you could see the answer of Mołot.